# android_listview

Tags: android

I want to open a new activity when an item is clicked in listview. How to do this.?
Here is the code :

```
package com.example.c_progams;
```

public class Second_listview extends ListActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.second_listview);

    setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.second_listview, type));
    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }



    });
}
```

static final String[] type = new String[]{

```
"Array", "Operator Overloading", "Inheritence", "Strings", "Pointers", "Files", "Misclaneous"
```

};

}

Comment: Put the code to start the activity in your onItemClick() method...

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: but how can i declare it for multiple items in the listview?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your Activity called code into onItemClick(..) Method

Like this:

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextScreen);

        }
```